# Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'search' is not present]

Tags: html, ajax, spring-boot

My controller can't pick the parameter. seach parameter remains null

```
@GetMapping("/api/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<ProductDto>> search(@RequestParam("search") String search) {  
    return new ResponseEntity<>(searchProductDao.search(search), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here is html part:

```
<form class="form-header" onsubmit="return false;" method="GET">
    <input class="au-input au-input-xl" id="search" type="text" name="search"
                                placeholder="Search for data ..." />
        <button class="au-btn-submit" type="submit">
                                Search
        </button>
</form>
```

And Ajax method:

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function () {
    // $('.product-box').append(output);
    let text = $('#search').val();
    if(text != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/search',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: text,
            contentType: text,
            success: function (listOfDtoProducts) {
                $.each(listOfBooks, function (i, p) {
                    $('.product-box').append(fillingBlockOfProduct(p));
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

})

function displayingBooks() {
$.ajax({
url: '/api/books',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (listOfBooks) {
$.each(listOfBooks, function (i, book) {
$('.product-box').append(fillingBlockOfProduct(book));
});
},

Comment: please provide the error and the path mapping of your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're only sending the search input value to the ajax query.

The spring controller is looking for a parameter named 'search'

instead of

```
data: text,
```

try

```
data:'search='+text,
```

or

```
let dataObj = {'search': text};
...
data: dataObj,
```

Comment: yeah, but I thought that the right way of solution would be getting RequestParam from html. Please take a look at https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-requestparam-annotation#:~:text=In%20controller%20class%3A,provides%20it%20to%20view%20page.

Comment: I don't understand. Here you're using jquery ajax to send the date not a browser form submit.